# Ошибка: "Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "", or the name is ambiguous."

Tags: sql, sql-server

Здравствуйте, создаю таблицу и ставлю ограничение, завернутое в функцию, которая проверяет чтобы название фирмы состояло либо только из русских либо только из латинских символов

```
Create table Firm
(FirmId int not null primary key,
 Firm nvarchar(30) check([dbo].[CheckFirm]([Firm])='True'),
 FoundYear int)
```

Код Функции:

```
Create function dbo.checkFirm(@f nvarchar(30))
Returns bit-- ([dbo].[CheckFirm]([Firm])='true')
As
  begin
    Declare @x int =0, @i int = 2, @s varchar(1), @b bit
    set @s = substring(@f, 1, 1)
    if @s like '[а-яА-Я]'
    begin
    set @x =1
    while @i <= len(@f) 
    begin set @s= substring (@f, @i, 1)
        if @s between 'а' and 'я'
            set @x=@x+1
        set @i=@i+1
    end
    end

    else
    if @s like '[a-zA-Z]'
    begin
    set @x =1
    while @i <= len(@f) 
    begin set @s= substring (@f, @i, 1)
        if @s between 'a' and 'z'
            set @x=@x+1
        set @i=@i+1
    end
    end

if @x = len(@f)
 set @b = 'True'
else
 set @b = 'False'
Return @b
end
go
```

выдает ошибку следующего содержания:

> Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Cannot find either column "dbo" or
>   the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.CheckFirm", or the name is
>   ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему функция такая сложная? достаточно проверить три выражения:

```
FIRM like '%[а-яА-Я]%'
FIRM like '%[a-zA-Z]%'
FIRM like '%[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]%'
```

Из них только одно из первых двух должно быть истинным. Это, кстати, и в CREATE TABLE вполне помещается...

Comment: как-то не додумался до такой реализации, спасибо за подсказку)